# AutoIt - Confirmation that function send has been executed

Tags: autoit

I'm working with function send() and I was wondering if there's any way of confirming it works apart from expecting the action it is to undertake.

Below is code indicating how I'm utilising function send to send instructions held in an array.

```
      Switch $ch
       Case "A"
           MsgBox (0, "SWITCH STATEMENT", $userconfigasarray[1])
           ;$myvar = $userconfigasarray[1]
           Send("{"& $userconfigasarray[1] &"}")
           MsgBox (0, "SEND STATUS", "SEND HAS BEEN CALLED")
           ;Exit
       Case "B"
           MsgBox (0, "SWITCH STATEMENT", $userconfigasarray[2])
           $myvar = $userconfigasarray[2]
           ;send("{LEFT}")
           send("{"& $myvar &"}")
        Case "C"
           MsgBox (0, "SWITCH STATEMENT", $userconfigasarray[3])
           $myvar = $userconfigasarray[3]
           send("{"& $myvar &"}")        
       Case "D"
           MsgBox (0, "SWITCH STATEMENT", $userconfigasarray[4])
           $myvar = $userconfigasarray[4]
           send("{"& $myvar &"}")
       Case "E"
           MsgBox (0, "SWITCH STATEMENT", $userconfigasarray[5])
           $myvar = $userconfigasarray[5]
           send("{"& $myvar &"}")
       Case "F"
           MsgBox (0, "SWITCH STATEMENT", $userconfigasarray[6])
           $myvar = $userconfigasarray[6]
           send("{"& $myvar &"}")
           ;loggit("SEND STATUS - SEND HAS BEEN CALLED")
       Case "G"
           MsgBox (0, "SWITCH STATEMENT", $userconfigasarray[7])
           $myvar = $userconfigasarray[7]
           send("{"& $myvar &"}")        
       Case "H"
           MsgBox (0, "SWITCH STATEMENT", $userconfigasarray[8])
           $myvar = $userconfigasarray[8]
           send("{"& $myvar &"}")        
       Case "1"
           MsgBox (0, "SWITCH STATEMENT", $userconfigasarray[9])
           $myvar = $userconfigasarray[9]
           send("{"& $myvar &"}")        
       Case "2"
           MsgBox (0, "SWITCH STATEMENT", $userconfigasarray[10])
           $myvar = $userconfigasarray[10]
           send("{"& $myvar &"}")        
       Case "3"
           MsgBox (0, "SWITCH STATEMENT", $userconfigasarray[11])
           $myvar = $userconfigasarray[11]
           send("{"& $myvar &"}")        
       Case "4"
           MsgBox (0, "SWITCH STATEMENT", $userconfigasarray[12])
           $myvar = $userconfigasarray[12]
           send("{"& $myvar &"}")        
       Case "5"
           MsgBox (0, "SWITCH STATEMENT", $userconfigasarray[13])
           $myvar = $userconfigasarray[13]
           Send("{"& $myvar &"}")        
       Case "6"
           MsgBox (0, "SWITCH STATEMENT", $userconfigasarray[14])
           $myvar = $userconfigasarray[14]
           send("{"& $myvar &"}")        
       Case "7"
           MsgBox (0, "SWITCH STATEMENT", $userconfigasarray[15])
           $myvar = $userconfigasarray[15]
           send("{"& $myvar &"}")        
       Case "8"
           MsgBox (0, "SWITCH STATEMENT", $userconfigasarray[16])
           $myvar = $userconfigasarray[16]
           send("{"& $myvar &"}")        
       Case "9"
           MsgBox (0, "SWITCH STATEMENT", $userconfigasarray[17])
           $myvar = $userconfigasarray[17]
           send("{"& $myvar &"}")        
       Case Else
           MsgBox (0, "SWITCH STATEMENT", "Can't handle '" & $ch & "' <0x" & Hex(Asc($ch), 2) & ">")
           ;loggit("Can't handle '" & $ch & "' <0x" & Hex(Asc($ch), 2) & ">")

     EndSwitch
```

I can confirm the correct syntax for the instructions is being held in the array ready for sending through function send() i.e.

- $userconfigasarray[1] holds ESCAPE
- $userconfigasarray[2] holds APPSKEY etc

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, there is no case for the send function failing in what it does. If it works on your setup sending keys to a notepad window, it will work for everything else.

That's not to say failure is impossible. It's just such a fringe case that accounting for it is not really necessary. If you really do think the `Send` function itself was failing, you could try seeing if the winapi last error message is set (see the `_WinAPI_GetLastErrorMessage` function, make sure you use `_WinAPI_SetLastError` to set it to zero beforehand).

It is more likely that the window doesn't receive the keystrokes, or ignores them. To test that you could just read the window afterwards.

The `Send` function should be a last resort. The `ControlSend` function is a lot better as it does not require the window to be active (or even visible) to work.